# App flickers and won't start on Pixel Fold foldable screen

Tags: applications, google-pixel

On my new Pixel Fold, the Mixcloud app won't start and just flickers (in a way that could induce an epileptic fit in a person with epilepsy) when I try to open it on the foldable screen. It works fine on the outside screen, which is a more normal phone size.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Rotating the screen fixed the problem.

However, the app still has the same problem if I try to use it in Split Screen mode. So I guess I can't use it in Split Screen mode.